# How do I install CVS on Ubuntu manually from a rpm file?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, cvs

I have downloaded `cvs-1.11.18-cvshome.org.FC1.1.i386.rpm` from CVS homepage and I want to install CVS manually on Ubuntu, since I don't have an internet connection. How do I install it?

Comment: Get the DEB. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cvs

Comment: @Zoredache: thanks for the link I updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rpm is a binary package for RedHat-similar systems. What do you mean by manually?

- if you want to build it from source: download the latest tar.gz file from http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/source/stable/ and read the INSTALL file
- if you want to install a binary look for the correct .deb package for your Ubuntu distribution (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cvs)

Comment: Normally you enter a command apt-get cvs etc, but I don't have an internet connection. Can't I use rpm file on Ubuntu?

Comment: It might be possible, but it may be very difficult.  The tools needed for RPM on Ubuntu are not default.  The RPM probably requires versions of libraries not present on your system.

Comment: @alwbtc: you can also download the .deb (instead of RPM) package and install it locally with `apt`

Comment: Ok, I downloaded tar.gz file form Matteo's link and followed instructions in README file. thanks.

Comment: @alwbtc Doable but the .dep binary is easier ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install the *alien* package.
Details are [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/install-rpm-files-in-debian-and-ubuntu.html)

> If you can’t find .deb debian package in any of the debian,ubuntu repositories or elsewhere, you can use the alien package converter to install the .rpm file.